# Ruby regexp to parse command line

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I parse strings in ruby like many command line utilities do? I've got strings similar to `"command [--opt1=...] [--enable-opt2] --opt3=... arg1"` and methods similar to `command(opt1,opt2,opt3,arg1...)`. I want to let arguments to come in random order, some of them can be optional.

At the moment I wrilte regexp every time I need to parse new command, as for example
to parse "lastpost --chan=your_CHANNEL /section/"

I have this regular expression:

```
    text = "lastpost --chan=0chan.ru /s/"
    command = (text.match /^\w+/)[0]
    args = text.gsub(/^\w+/,'')
    if args =~ /[[:blank:]]*(--chan\=([[:graph:]]+)[[:blank:]]+)*\/?(\w+)\/?/
        chan = $2
        section = $3
        do_command(chan,section)
    else
        puts "wrong args"
    end
```

I wish i had create_regexp(opts,args), which should produce regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found [optparse](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/OptionParser.html) can do it for me